# autocomplete inputs by first input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, tags

I need help combining 2 codes into one.

The first on is an input with autocomlete tags:

HTML:

```
<h3>Type in the name of your favorite programming language!</h3>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var languages = ["Ada", "Java", "LISP", "Javascript", "PHP", "C", "C++", "Visual Basic", "HTML", "CSS", "JQuery"];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: languages
  });
});
```

The second is 3 inputs that autofill by option selected:

http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/

I want the final result to be first 4 inputs, the first is auto complete by tags and when you select a tag than it autofills the other inputs based on the same connection

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/309/

```js
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids[0] = "6";
use[0] = "bsmith";
ful[0] = "Buddy Smith";

ids[1] = "2";
use[1] = "lsmith";
ful[1] = "Libbie Smith";

ids[2] = "4";
use[2] = "asmith";
ful[2] = "Andy Smith";


function Choice(autoEle) {
  if(autoEle === 'use') {
    selectedIndex = use.indexOf( $('#use').val());
  } else if(autoEle === 'ful') {
   selectedIndex = ful.indexOf( $('#ful').val());
  } else {
   selectedIndex = ids.indexOf( $('#ids').val());
  }
  

  document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById("use").value = use[selectedIndex];
  document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[selectedIndex];
}

$("#use").autocomplete({
  source: use,
  select: function(){
    $('#selectUsers option[value="' + (use.indexOf( $('#use').val()) + 1) + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
    Choice('use');
  }
});
      
$("#ids").autocomplete({
  source: ids,
  select: function(){
    $('#selectUsers option[value="' + (ids.indexOf( $('#ids').val()) + 1) + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
    Choice('ids');
  }
});
      
$("#ful").autocomplete({
  source: ful,
  select: function(){
    $('#selectUsers option[value="' + (ful.indexOf( $('#ful').val()) + 1) + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
    Choice('ful');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>ids <input type="text" id="ids" name="id" ></p>
  <p>use <input type="text" id="use" name="username" ></p>
  <p>ful <input type="text" id="ful" name="full_name" ></p>
</form>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @DigiNetEvents I've updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: @DigiNetEvents Welcome buddy :)